# Rails: very elaborate associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm having a lot of issues with my messaging system. I would love some help. It works fully, except the `User` `Message` relation. I'm attempting to relate `authored_messages` to `User` and `received_messages` to `User`. The roadblock from doing this is that `received_messages` is supposed to go through two different models (`ConversationUser` and `Conversation`), whereas `authored_messages` should be a direct relationship using the message's `user_id` field. Here she is:

**Models**

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many(
:conversation_users, 
inverse_of: :user,
dependent: :destroy
)

has_many(
:conversations, 
through: :conversation_users
)

# has_many :messages   ?

# has_many(            ?
# :received_messages,
# class_name: "Messages",
# through: :conversations,
# source: :conversation_users
# )
```

Message:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user                               # ?

belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User"      # ?

belongs_to(
:conversation, 
inverse_of: :messages
)

has_many(
:conversation_users, 
through: :conversation
)

accepts_nested_attributes_for :conversation
```

Conversation:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base  

has_many(
:messages, 
inverse_of: :conversation
)

has_many(
:conversation_users, 
inverse_of: :conversation
)

has_many(
:users, 
through: :conversation_users
)

accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
```

ConversationUser (a join model):

```
class ConversationUser < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to(
:user, 
inverse_of: :conversation_users
)

belongs_to(
:conversation, 
inverse_of: :conversation_users
)

has_many(
:messages,
through: :conversation
)

delegate :users, to: :conversation
accepts_nested_attributes_for :conversation
```

**Migrations**

User

```
# None involved with messaging
```

Message

```
t.integer :user_id
t.integer :conversation_id
t.text :body
```

Conversation

```
# None, except the :id field. It helps relate messages and conversation_users
```

ConversationUser

```
t.integer :user_id
t.integer :conversation_id
```

It seems to me that I'd be adding something like this ([how do I associate one model twice to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606565/how-do-i-associate-one-model-twice-to-another)), but I'm having a hard time applying this to my models. And to further clarify how these associations work, this is a really simplified visual:

```
users--->conversation_users
  :             |
  :             |
  V             V
messages<---conversation
```

I'd really, really appreciate any help I can get, and hopefully this question will help other people dealing with complex associations!

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention it, but this messaging system can have as many recipients (conversation_users) as the sender decides. (when the sender creates a new conversation)

Comment: Quick question - why do you have brackets around multi-line associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out via further trial and error. I was making it much harder than it was. Here are the correct changes for the `User` and `Message` classes and the relations between them:

Message

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user                # This

belongs_to(
:conversation, 
inverse_of: :messages
)

has_many(
:conversation_users, 
through: :conversation
)

has_many(                       # This
:recipients, 
class_name: "User", 
through: :conversation_users,
source: :user
)

accepts_nested_attributes_for :conversation
```

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many(
:conversation_users, 
inverse_of: :user,
dependent: :destroy
)

has_many(
:conversations, 
through: :conversation_users
)

has_many :messages               # This

has_many(                        # This
:received_messages, 
class_name: "Message", 
through: :conversations,
source: :messages
)
```

The associations I marked with `# This` are the four relations I was having trouble connecting in the first place. This messaging system is a unique four-model messaging system that supports (hypothetically) limitless conversation users. Its behavior is not unlike many other social network messaging systems out there. It is fully functional, and any of these four class objects can be accessed from any other related class object. I hope this Q/A will serve as a great reference for anyone trying to build a similar messaging system. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**How do you know whether a message is `sent` or `received`?**

In your `message` model, you're only referencing `user_id` and `conversation_id`. You'd typically want `recipient_id` and `sender_id` instead of just `user_id`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :conversation_users, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :conversations, through: :conversation_users
end

class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :conversation_users
    has_many :users, through: conversation_users

    has_many :sent_messages, class: "Message", through: :conversations, foreign_key: "sender_id", source: :user
    has_many :received_messages, class: "Message", through: :conversations, foregin_key: "recipient_id", source: :user
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :conversation
    belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", primary_key: "sender_id"
    belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", primary_key: "recipient_id"
end

messages
t.integer :sender_id
t.integer :recipient_id
t.integer :conversation_id
t.text :body
```

This should yield:

```
@user.conversations[x].sent_messages
@user.conversations[x].received_messages
```

Comment: The message model can't have a recipient_id field because it has many recipients. The recipients are all of the conversation_users. Each conversation user has a conversation that has many messages. But I'm wondering how to go through all three relationships to the message model and parse out the messages that do not have the user_id equal to the receiving user (back through the three models)